# I can't enter the control panel of my wordpress site after channing the URL to https://

Tags: admin, 404-error

I have a big problem and I am somewhat panicking about this one.
My website didn't have https enabled so i went to the settings panel, changed the website link to https://andthewebsitesname. Now when I want to login, it just sends me to the 404 page saying my connection for this site is not secure.
How can I undo this? I can't login right now.

Comment: Did you actually get an SSL certificate? You need one to use https.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the database (for example, using phpMyAdmin), you can change the values in table "wp_options" -- the fields are near the top... "site_url" and "home"

You can also set this in the wp-config.php file.

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );
```

https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/

Comment: You sir, are a godsent.

Comment: This didn't specifically work for me but when I went to the website that hosts my website, I was able to install SSL and now I managed to login again.